# Good way to filter multiple DB columns in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to filter my results agains multiple **DB** columns but the way I'm doing it right now doesn't seem Laravel-ish at all :)

Is there a better way? I don't want to pile up all those `sql` statements at the end.

```
$data = Input::except('_token');

        if (isset($data['passenger_name']))
        {
            $passenger_name = $data['passenger_name'];
        } else {
            $passenger_name = '*';
        }

        if (isset($data['passenger_lastname']))
        {
            $passenger_lastname = $data['passenger_lastname'];
        } else {
            $passenger_lastname = '*';
        }

        // Run query
        $q = Reservation::where('passenger_firstname', 'LIKE', '%'. $passenger_name .'%')
                        ->where('passenger_lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $passenger_lastname .'%')
                        ->get();

        return View::make('dashboard')->with('reservations', $q);
```

These are just two of many criteria i have to run queries against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$query = Reservation::query();
if(Input::has('passenger_name')) {
    $query->where('passenger_name', Input::get('passenger_name'));
}
if(Input::has('passenger_lastname')) {
    $query->where('passenger_lastname', Input::get('passenger_lastname'));
}
$reservations = $query->get();
return View::make('dashboard')->with('reservations', $reservations);
```

Comment: Any way to do this in the same inputfield? So one input to filter. This checks if name OR firstname is 'LIKE' ...

Comment: @NicolasV, Didn't understand the `LIKE`, can you please rephrase it?

Comment: Oh thanks for the comment. Found it after some searching.. I was looking for this `orwhere` in a call `$query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $input .'%')->orwhere('firstname', 'LIKE', '%'. $input .'%')->get();`

Comment: Oh! Glad you figured it out, all the best @NicolasV :-)